# Cheap Method for Audio/video transmission in a building

Tags: video, live

I would like to know how I can handle video transmission in the a 2 story building, from the upper floor to the down floor?
There 2 possible cases:
-unidirectional transmission: the transmission will be done from the upper floor to the down floor;
-bidirectional transmission: the transmission will be done from the upper floor to the down floor, and also from the down floor to the upper floor.

I have a very low budget for this so need cheap options.

Comment: Can you provide further clarification on cheap?  Does it need to be wireless?  The cheapest possible approach is going to be a distribution amplifier and a length of cable, but the exact type of signal you are sending makes a big difference, as does the distance and materials of the building.

Comment: Hi Henderson, I think that a wired solution is better than a wireless one to avoid constraint on building materials. The budget is between 500$ and 1000$. I wish I could have a solution using a local network configuration, and another one using not a local network but an analogical signal. Thank you.

Comment: still need to know what kind of signal you are sending (HD, SD, one feed, multiple feeds, etc) and distance.

Comment: I will use HD. About the feed and multiple feeds question, I don't know what it refers to. I would like the simpliest solution due to budget constraint. We would like to be able to broadcast audio/video from the upper floor in live to the down floor. If the solution is not expensive, the possibility to be able to send an audio/video feedback from the down floor the upper one will be appreciate. The distance is approximatively 50 meters.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, neither of which is particular expensive.  You can either use a component cable with a distribution amplifier or if you prefer a digital signal, there are wireless HDMI transmitters that will also work well.

A distribution amplifier and a repeater are essentially the same thing, just slightly different purposes. A distribution amplifier boosts the power of an analog signal to account for the attenuation when sending it over one or more lines or a long line. A repeater is similar, it reads the signal in on one side and outputs it again on the other. The main difference is that the repeater will reduce line noise since it is interpreting the signal rather than just boosting it.

You could try doing a wired HDMI, but it would likely be quite pricy.
HDMI is a digital signal that is designed in such a way that it doesn't handle long distances well on the wire. Currently, the effective reliable limit for an HDMI cable is about 10 meters. To make a 50 meter run reliable, you would need 4 repeaters and 5 10 meter rated HDMI cables. This is going to be far, far more expensive than a wireless HDMI unit that is rated for even twice the distance.

You could try just using a 50 meter cable and hope that your hardware on each side is powerful enough to make sense of the data on the line, but I wouldn't expect it to be a reliable connection if you use a physical HDMI wire without at least 2 or 3 repeaters minimum.

So for reliable solutions, you can probably do the analog wire & distribution amplifier solution for about $150 or the wireless for about $250 to 350.  Putting a DA on both sides of the wire solution would allow for you to choose which way you wanted to send signal by plugging in the DA on that side.

Comment: Hi Henderson, thank you for your answer. Following this link, you'll find an image illustrating how I understand the implementation of the system. Is that correct? Also, what means «DA» in your answer? ![Audio/Video Transmission](http://tonguim.free.fr/divers/audioVideoTransmission.png)

Comment: DA is distribution amplifier.  You won't be able to use HDMI without repeaters at 50 meters length because it is too long for the HDMI standard.  You will either want to use wireless HDMI transmitters or use an analog component signal and a distribution amplifier.

Comment: Thanks Henderson. Do you confirm that the above picture can be use to implement the audio/video transmission system and that I will have to add to that HDMI repeaters and DA? Please what is the utility of DA, I mean why use it? Where should I place the DA on the picture? Also I guess that the HDMI standard cable is better than the wireless HDMI transmitters for audio/video transmission. Wireless communications often have to pass by many obstacles to offer a good quality result: signal strenght, air density, building materials, medical restrictions for some people, etc. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @cProg - see the updates to my answer that should provide further assistance.